# Looking for a string function or a query

Tags: sql, oracle

is there any string function or a query in oracle that gives the result i am looking for :

input - abc , output - zab it means my output should be character that comes before each letter in my input string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can do this with `translate()`:

```
select translate('abc', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy')
from dual
```

Comment: What if my input varies..like not only for abc if there are multiple patterns on input ?

Comment: @HemanthKumar . . . This answers the question that you asked, for all 26 letters encoded in ASCII-7, for any string you provide as the first argument.  If you have another question, ask it as another question, not in a comment.

Comment: Thanks i got it :) this was my first question in this forum so yet to learn the rules of posting questions.

Comment: @HemanthKumar: You could try to clarify (in your comments and in the original question - by editing it), that what you described ("abc" -> "zab") is an example, and that you expect a general solution. You would have to also explain what "multiple patterns" are. You could try by showing an input data set (e.g. a few rows of a table contents) and expected query output for those rows.